# Incorporate JS Callback Into HTML <img> Tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, youtube, youtube-api

I'm making a small application, and would like to integrate a YouTube section. I have a method of getting the user's YouTube icon:

This in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/communitychannel?fields=yt:username,media:thumbnail&alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=showImage"></script>
```

And this is the script:

```
<script>
function showImage(data)
{
  var name= data.entry.yt$username.$t;
  var url = data.entry.media$thumbnail.url;
  $(document).append("<img src='"+ url +"'/>");
}
</script>
```

I'm new with JS, can someone show me how I would now use this to integrate the URL given by the script above into an HTML  tag? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hello the $tumbnail returned by youtube is an array, you need to access position 0. Select body to add it.

```
var url = data.entry.media$thumbnail[0].url;
$('body').append("<img src='"+ url +"'/>");
```

Comment: Thanks, now how do I implement this into the <img> tag?